# Subclass overwriting parent static property

Tags: php, static

Tell me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure this is a bug in PHP.

```
<?php

class One {

    public static $var = 'hi';
}

class Two extends One {

    public static function set($var) {
        static::$var = $var;
    }
}

Two::set('bye');

var_dump(One::$var);
// bye
```

That script outputs 'bye', when I'm pretty sure it should be outputting 'hi'. What do you think?

I **do not** want to redeclare this in the subclass.

Answer (score 1):

*OP edited question, this was the answer before he mentioned he doesn't want to redeclare properties*

It's because `Two` shares `$var` with `One`.

If you would write it like this, then you would get the desired output

```
class One {

    public static $var = 'hi';
}

class Two extends One {

    public static $var = 'hi';

    public static function set($var) {
        static::$var = $var;
    }
}

Two::set('bye');

// you get hi
var_dump(One::$var);
// you get bye
var_dump(Two::$var);
```

Comment: I don't want to have to redeclare it in the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible, but if you don't want to redeclare simple define it in the constructor..

```
class One {

    public static $var = 'hi';
}

class Two extends One {

    public static $var;

    public function __construct(){
        self::$var = parent::$var;
    }

    public static function set($var) {
        self::$var = $var;
    }
}

Two::set('bye');

var_dump(One::$var);
var_dump(Two::$var);
```

Comment: how is that not redeclaring `$var`, you declared it in both classes?

Comment: yes I'm redeclaring, however it just don't make you change your var's in every time it appears (when you have to) and because I don't see why he doesn't want to redeclare.

Comment: I don't want to redeclare because it's for a framework and I can't know for sure that whoever uses it will redeclare this variable.

Comment: then you'll have to make it instance variables, and not static